# Inserting image as part of an email body in PHP

Tags: php, html, image, email

I am using following code to include an image in a page:

```
<img src="android_login_api/firmas/<?php echo $_GET['id'].'.JPG'?> " alt="">
```

It works fine and the picture is shown.

Now I need to include the same picture as part of the body in an email.

This is the variable that creates the email body:

```
$email_body = "This is the Proof of Delivery from Order: $order.\n".
                            "Received by: $rec";
```

I have tried to include the image in several ways, but I am always getting an error.
How could I insert the image correctly as part of the body?

Comment: use the full url protocol and sent out as HTML

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, I don´t know what you mean.

Comment: `<img src="http://example.com/path/to/your/img.jpg" alt="">` that's what he means. and dont forget to send it as html not plain text

Comment: @plonknimbuzz, my issues is that I need to combine file name as variable and file extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you will send this picture in an email body so you will need to get the full URL of the image starting with the website the image is hosted onto, and then set the source of the image to it's full URL, something like that:

```
<?php
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$imagePath = $domain.'path/to/image/'.$id;
$email_body = 'some text <img src="'.$imagePath.'"/> rest of body';
?>
```

I hope this will help